# Accessing values in xml values using generated integers in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, xml

I am trying to access xml values using a generated integer in Android Studio.

Right now my xml file contains string names ranging from q1 up to q100. In my java file I am using a random generated value to determine which one to select.

The only way I know to access a xml value is by the following example:

```
Button buttonA = (Button) findViewById(R.id.aButton);
buttonA.setText(R.string.q1);
```

I am trying to find a dynamic way so that my `setText()` method can use my random generated value instead of the direct value `R.string.q1`.

Comment: share your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer I was looking for!

```
String[] arrayFromXML;

public void questionGenerator() {
    Random gen = new Random();
    int value = gen.nextInt(4);

    arrayFromXML = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.arrayFromXML);

    xmlText.setText(arrayFromXML[value]);
}
```